# Encoded Json in URL giving exception

Tags: java, json

I am having a parameter that am passing in URL, in encoded form.
So If JSON is

```
{"size":{"value":"5\"x10\" Kraft (250 Envelopes) Value Pack"}, "color":{"value":""},"packSize":{"value":""},"style":{"value":""}}
```

Then in encoded form it will be :

```
%7B%22size%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%225%5C%22x10%5C%22%20Kraft%20(250%20Envelopes)%20Value%20Pack%22%7D%2C%20%22color%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22packSize%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22style%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D
```

Which when I get in my Java code I get like this :

```
{"size":{"value":"5\"x10\" Kraft (250 Envelopes) Value Pack"}, "color":{"value":""},"packSize":{"value":""},"style":{"value":""}}
```

And am having a class VariantContainer where I want to assign these values.

So I tried two ways, but am getting exception.

Approach 1 :

```
try {
   # variant is value I get from URL 
   JsonElement variantRequestJson = new JsonParser().parse(variant);


   variantContainer.setSize(variantApiRequestJson.getAsJsonObject().
                    get("size").getAsJsonObject().get("value").toString());

 # Similarly other variations, but its giving null pointer exception
 } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
}
```

Approach 2 :

```
try {
    variantContainer = gson.fromJson(variant, VariantContainer.class);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
  }
```

It gives exception :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 10
```

Let me know, what am missing. How can I get it in best way ?

VariantContainer class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class VariantContainer {
private String size;
private String color;
private String packSize;
private String style;

public String getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(String size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public String getStyle() {
    return style;
}

public void setStyle(String style) {
    this.style = style;
}

public String getPackSize() {
    return packSize;
}

public void setPackSize(String packSize) {
    this.packSize = packSize;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(this);
}
}
```

Comment: Your first option works for me for the JSON sample you provided. Your second option is answered by the duplicate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How option1 worked ? Is it not giving exception ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis For second case, I tried this thing also, But still getting same exception. May be because of double quotes in text !!

Comment: I don't get a `NullPointerException` when deserializing the JSON you provided and trying to access `size`, then `value`. The doubles quotes are correctly escaped. As the duplicate suggests, your `VariantContainer` POJO is in the "wrong" format. It doesn't match the format of the JSON.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can you share small code snippets for approaches

Comment: I don't have any. I tried what you have in your question, except I assume you meant `variantRequestJson.getAsJsonObject...` instead of `variantApiRequestJson.get...` in your first example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yup I meant the same. But then why am getting exception :(

Comment: You'll need to debug that your JSON is actually what you say it is. Or maybe the NPE is elsewhere. Can't help you with that, but see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What about second approach ? Can you correct me

Comment: You haven't posted your POJO code, but the duplicate already explains how types need to be mapped to corresponding JSON.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis By POJO here you mean variantContainer ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Added. Please check

Comment: Please take a look at the error, then take a look at the duplicate, then take a look at your `size` field. (A `String` does not match a JSON object, it matches a JSON string, but you have a JSON object.)